# Real effect of return value in ArrangeOverride method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout, arrangeoverride

I am trying to implement custom panel in WPF and I don't understand what the real effect of return value from `ArrangeOverride` method is. It seems that it is allways ok to return `finalSize` (the argument of `ArrangeOverride`) without changing it.

Is there a situation in which I should return something different than `finalSize`?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride(v=vs.110).aspx), `ArrangeOverride` returns

> The actual size used.

So if (for whatever reason) the actual size required by a Panel's children differs from `finalSize` in one or the other dimension, the method may return a different size.

It is however safe to always return `finalSize`. This would just mean that your Panel has already determined its final size during the measure pass, and did not adjust it during the actual arrangement of its children.